# Best way to enhance a widget in another package?

Tags: htmlwidgets

The `rgl` package exports a couple of `htmlwidgets`:  the one produced by `rgl::rglwidget()` and the one produced by `rgl::playwidget()`.  In a separate package, I'd like to export some Javascript code that will work with these.  (It will be a new control that can be handled by `rgl::playwidget()` and will modify an rgl widget.)

So this code is much less than a widget; it won't ever be displayed on its own.  It needs to have the `rgl` code loaded first, and then it will add some `rglwidgetClass` methods.

How should this be done?  Is there a way to make an invisible widget, that just exists so that dependencies can be declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way, but here is one way to do what I want.

The idea is that the `htmltools` package allows you to attach dependencies to just about any HTML object that you're outputing.  For example,

```
library(htmltools)
p("This is some text", htmlDependency( .... ))
```

will automatically cause the `htmlDependency` to be loaded into the header of the created web page.